# Does it make sense to create a file with only the "export" defined?

Tags: flutter, dart, import, export

Let's say you have a Flutter project with the following directory structure.

```
 main.dart
>animal
  dog.dart
  cat.dart
  human.dart
  animal.dart  //It's import file
```

The contents of `animal.dart` here are as follows.

```
export 'dog.dart';
export 'cat.dart';
export 'human.dart';
```

Is there a need to create a so-called "importer," which is a file that `exports` files at the same level? Could this potentially be counterproductive and lead to obfuscation instead?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

These are called barrel files.  They allow you to change the folder structure of your code without changing the code that imports it.  In your example, imagine moving dog.dart, cat.dart and human.dart into a mammals folder, and adding folders for birds, fish, etc.  You only need to change animal.dart, vs changing every file that imports one or more of them.  This is indispensable when making libraries.